# How to display a USB disk icon on the top bar?

Tags: indicator

How can I make my ubuntu 12.04 to display the USB icon on the top bar(together with input method swither,weather indicator...) when I add my disk(any disk) to my pc, not to add it on the launcher bar?

Comment: Could you explain a little more what U disk is? Perhaps you can find a picture of what it looks like and post that?

Comment: apologise for my poor Chingish(Chinese English),I mean the removable flash disk, just like Kingston  DT101 G2 I got,when I attach it to my computer, A flash disk icon generates on the left unity launcher bar, but I think it's more convenient if it displayed on the top bar

Answer (score 0):

**There is a USB Safe Removal Indicator**

**Description**

> Safely remove USB thumb drives, mounted SD Cards and more with ‘USB
>   Safe Removal application indicator’ (Or Indicator-unmount’ for short
>   ;) ). The tiny app doesn’t sing, it certainly doesn’t dance ,but it
>   does do what it says on the tin: let you quickly eject mounted drives.

[Download Information Here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7138409/indicator-usb/indicator.html)

[OMG Ubuntu Article Source here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/01/the-omg-guide-to-must-have-indicator-applets)

**IMPORTANT:** Keep in mind this article dates from January 2011 and have not seen any updates for 12.04 LTS.  Both the Debs and the Source code are available from the link provided above.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I want, but I found another application called "Docky"

Comment: Ok, so that others can benefit this question and answer, can you upvote the anser and acceptit as the correct response.